# Tempreture distribution in a furnace

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, cfd, temperature, fluent

I am simulating a furnace as follows:

[image]

Is it possible to capture temperature distribution in this furnace without designing intake fan? Which kind of boundary conditions can replace with intake fan?
In this model, there is a electrical element for generating heat (in fact, transferring heat to air flow). How can I set this element as a boundary condition?

In addition, There are four cylinder in this model and they rotate. I want to obtain temperature distribution around these cylinders.

This problem is unsteady an 3D. Firstly (t=0), temperature in furnace is 25 but when air flow cross air duct and electrical element, temperature in exit of duct is equal to 200 C. All of furnace walls are adiabatic. Therefore, We have two kind of work(electrical work and mechanical work) and Q=0.

What information (pressure, temperature, heat flux, power and ...) should I have for boundary conditions in parts of Fan and element?

Major goal in this simulation is to find that temperature distribution (inside the furnace) is uniform or not (i.e 200 C).

I am grateful that guide me and give me useful links and documents in this case.

Comment: In the real world, furnace temperature distribution is determined by placing thermocouples at various locations; As I remember Mil Spec. H 6872 defines the testing necessary to meet US Federal qualifications.  For critical parts , thermocouples are attached directly to the part, each part.

Comment: Are you interested to model this theoretically or numerically? What background do you have already to do the required modeling? For example, have you modeled any of the system components by themselves?

Comment: "Are you interested to model this theoretically or numerically? "
Yes
Somewhat I have experience on the simulation and modelling. I want to start in this field.

Comment: I would like to see a clearer definition of the problem, its known values, its assumptions, and its core formulations. Numerical simulations and modeling only succeed from solid foundations of theory and a well-designed system. I fear you have neither. Prove otherwise.

Comment: Would you like to guide me in this case?! I don't understand your mean from these questions. I only want to learn and increase my information in this field.
Thanks.

Comment: I answered these. [Heat Sink](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23132/how-would-one-calculate-the-of-heat-not-absorbed-by-a-heat-sink/23145#23145) |  [Air Cooled Solid](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23518/calculation-for-heat-transfer-rate-cooling-capacity-for-air-cooled-solid/23526#23526) | [Temperature in Box](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/how-do-i-calculate-the-temperature-change-inside-a-box-with-a-heat-source-what/23207#23207) Can you re-develop your post based on these examples.

Comment: How can see the pictures in the posts? I can't see the pictures. Thanks.

Comment: I see the pictures. I cannot comment why you cannot see them.